# Oracle to Postgres - Convert Keep dense_rank query

Tags: postgresql, oracle, dense-rank

New to Postgresql and trying to convert an Oracle query to Postgres that uses keep dense_rank.

Here is the Oracle query that works properly:

```
SELECT 
    dbx.bundle_id, 
    j.JOB_CD||'_'||d.doc_type_cd||wgc.ending_cd as job_doc_type_wgt_grp,
    b.create_date,
    min (A.ADDRESS1) keep ( dense_rank first order by a.POSTAL_CD) as first_address,
    max (A.ADDRESS1) keep ( dense_rank last order by a.POSTAL_CD) as last_address,
    min (A.DOCUMENT_ID) keep ( dense_rank first order by a.POSTAL_CD) as first_docid,
    max (A.DOCUMENT_ID) keep ( dense_rank last order by a.POSTAL_CD) as last_docid,
    min (doc.original_img_name) keep ( dense_rank first order by a.POSTAL_CD) as first_doc_name,
    max (doc.original_img_name) keep ( dense_rank last order by a.POSTAL_CD) as first_doc_name,
    COUNT(distinct a.DOCUMENT_ID) as doc_count,
    SUM(B.PAGES) AS BUNDLE_PAGE_COUNT
FROM ADDRESS A
JOIN DOC_BUNDLE_XREF DBX ON (DBX.DOCUMENT_ID = A.DOCUMENT_ID)
JOIN DOCUMENT DOC ON DOC.DOCUMENT_ID = DBX.DOCUMENT_ID
JOIN BUNDLE B ON B.BUNDLE_ID = DBX.BUNDLE_ID
JOIN JOB J ON J.JOB_ID = B.JOB_ID
JOIN DOC_TYPE D ON D.DOC_TYPE_ID=B.DOC_TYPE_ID
JOIN WEIGHT_GROUP_CD WGC ON WGC.WEIGHT_GROUP_CD_ID = B.WEIGHT_GROUP_CD_ID
WHERE A.ADDRESS_TYPE_ID  = 
    (SELECT MAX( address_type_id )
    FROM ADDRESS AI
    WHERE  AI.document_id =A.DOCUMENT_ID)
AND DBX.BUNDLE_ID in (1404,1405,1407)
group by dbx.BUNDLE_ID, j.JOB_CD||'_'||d.doc_type_cd||wgc.ending_cd, b.create_date;
```

Here's the PG version:

```
SELECT 
    dbx.bundle_id, 
    j.JOB_CD||'_'||d.doc_type_cd||wgc.ending_cd as job_doc_type_wgt_grp,
    b.create_date,
    FIRST_VALUE(A.ADDRESS1) OVER (order by a.POSTAL_CD) as first_address,
    LAST_VALUE(A.ADDRESS1) OVER (order by a.POSTAL_CD) as last_address,
    FIRST_VALUE(A.DOCUMENT_ID) OVER (order by a.POSTAL_CD) as first_docid,
    LAST_VALUE(A.DOCUMENT_ID) OVER (order by a.POSTAL_CD) as last_docid,
    FIRST_VALUE(doc.original_img_name) OVER (order by a.POSTAL_CD) as first_doc_name,
    LAST_VALUE(doc.original_img_name) OVER (order by a.POSTAL_CD) as first_doc_name,
    COUNT(distinct a.DOCUMENT_ID) as doc_count,
    SUM(B.PAGES) AS BUNDLE_PAGE_COUNT
FROM ADDRESS A
JOIN DOC_BUNDLE_XREF DBX ON (DBX.DOCUMENT_ID = A.DOCUMENT_ID)
JOIN DOCUMENT DOC ON DOC.DOCUMENT_ID = DBX.DOCUMENT_ID
JOIN BUNDLE B ON B.BUNDLE_ID = DBX.BUNDLE_ID
JOIN JOB J ON J.JOB_ID = B.JOB_ID
JOIN DOC_TYPE D ON D.DOC_TYPE_ID=B.DOC_TYPE_ID
JOIN WEIGHT_GROUP_CD WGC ON WGC.WEIGHT_GROUP_CD_ID = B.WEIGHT_GROUP_CD_ID
 WHERE A.ADDRESS_TYPE_ID  = (
    SELECT MAX( address_type_id )
    FROM ADDRESS AI
    WHERE  AI.document_id =A.DOCUMENT_ID)
 AND DBX.BUNDLE_ID in (1404,1405,1407)
 group by dbx.BUNDLE_ID, j.JOB_CD||'_'||d.doc_type_cd||wgc.ending_cd, b.create_date;
```

Running this statement yields the following error:

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "a.address1" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I've tried `MIN` and `MAX` in place of `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE`, same results.  The same error happens on all of the other `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` functions.

What am I missing here? Any idea why it doesn't recognize `a.address1` (or any of the other columns) as being in an aggregate?

I'm using DBeaver version 21 to run these queries if that makes any difference. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.